# Microsoft EDGE message: SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, microsoft-edge

Error message only in edge browser, look like edge does not like default function parameter value `flag = false`, what is right way?

```js
function func(flag = false)
{
  alert("Hate edges");
}

func();
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters.  This isn't valid in most browsers, but *some* browsers have support for it in their superset, particularly if they support ES6 natively.

Answer (score 2):

Default parameter values are *presently* [supported behind a flag](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/defaultparameteres6?filter=f3f0000bf&search=default) in Microsoft Edge. To enable them, visit *about:flags*, and check *Enable experimental JavaScript features*.

If you'd like to use a feature like this, I'd encourage you to consider using a transpiler like Babel or TypeScript, which will produce ES5 compliant syntax for things.

For example, [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html) yields the following:

```js
function func(flag) {
    if (flag === void 0) { flag = false; }
    alert("Hate edges");
}
func();
```